# KPL AWS Kinesis Producer library failure without error messages

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I'm running KPL inside dropwizard. Following is my code.

```
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new
            BasicAWSCredentials("XXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
    kinesis = new KinesisProducer(new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .setRegion("ap-south-1")
            .setRecordMaxBufferedTime(100)
    );
    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> future = kinesis.addUserRecord("ctm-prod", "default_partition", data);
    UserRecordResult m = future.get();
```

The code gets blocked at `future.get()` forever.
No error message gets logged.

PS: I have tried using the same access keys via boto and java sdk. It works

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading kinesis producer version to the latest.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/issues/81